# A set of glossed phrases do not align to a list (uses linguex package)

Tags: formatting, linguistics, linguex

I've loaded a set of packages as shown below in the main.tex file

```
\usepackage{linguex}
\usepackage{tipa}
\usepackage{pst-vowel}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian,english]{babel}
\usepackage{anyfontsize}
\usepackage[margin=1in.]{geometry}
```

At a separate nominalmorph.tex file, I have written the following lines to give three glossed examples

```
\begin{exe}
    \ex. kauvrun du Ivan \\
            dog of Ivan \\
            Ivan's dog \\
    \ex. za kakurogo du Karulas \\
         ART.PL chicken of Karulas \\
         Karulas' chickens \\
    \exg. jesha du thea \\
      strength of god \\
\begin{exe}
```

However the output does not align itself but forms a diagonal

[image]

I'm accustomed in using LaTex for physics but this is the first time using it for linguistics. Any ideas? A solution that does not define a new command is preferred.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436). Please complete your code to provide a a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228). A small document we can compile is much more useful than a couple of fragments of code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wasn't able to replicate the cascading indentation with the MWE you provided, but I've identified some problems with your MWE and provided a working version.

**Watch out for these:**

- You can't put a `.` after a length, so I changed `\usepackage[margin=1in.]{geometry}` to `\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}`.
- `linguex` doesn't use `\begin{exe}` (that's from `gb4e`), but even if it did, you would need to end with `\end{exe}`, not `\begin{exe}` again.
- All `linguex` examples need to be followed by a blank line (see p. 1 of the documentation). Without this, I can't even get the file to compile, but I think this would be the source of your cascading indentation if your configuration does let you compile without these blank lines.
- Examples with interlinear glossing need to be introduced with `\exg.`, not `\ex.`.

**Working example:**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{linguex}
\usepackage{tipa}
\usepackage{pst-vowel}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian,english]{babel}
\usepackage{anyfontsize}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\exg. kauvrun du Ivan \\
            dog of Ivan \\
            Ivan's dog \\

\exg. za kakurogo du Karulas \\
         \textsc{art.pl} chicken of Karulas \\
         Karulas' chickens \\         

\exg. jesha du thea \\
      strength of god \\

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! The blank line after the glosses did the trick. I also thank you for the extra problems you saw in the code. Giving it upvote :)

Comment: Good to hear. If it solved your problem, you could [accept the answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 1):

The answer is simply that `linguex` is sensitive to blank lines (ends the environment) and will treat `\\` on a line to mean that the example environment is continuing, so a lack of `\\` on your translation line will do the trick before a blank link then starting your next example.

```
Some text

\exg. za kakurogo du Karulas \\
\textsc{art.pl} chicken of Karulas \\
`Karulas' chickens'  

\exg. jesha du thea \\
strength of god \\
`strength o'God'

Some more text.
```

`\\` at the end of your translation line plus a blank line before you start another text block or example (as in Jason Zentz's answer) will simply increase your vertical spacing as the blank line will be treated as the last line of the environment. The same is true between subexamples, so you need neither a `\\` nor a blank line.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{linguex}

\begin{document}

\noindent Some text

\ex.
\ag. an example\\
\textsc{art.indef} example\\
`an example'
\bg. another one\\
another one\\
`another one'

Some more text.

\end{document}
```

Best practice: between examples, a blank line and between subexamples, nothing.

I often use `\\` at the end of the translation line to include urls for my data:

```
\exg. an example\\
\textsc{art.indef} example\\
`an example'\\
\url{http://tex.stackexchange.com/posts/232456/}
```

Then a blank line

And this will keep the url within the example's environment (using whichever hyperlink package you want).

[image: with url]

Comment: You're right, I'm thinking of subexamples and single examples. I'll edit with more detail.

Comment: +1. I've deleted my earlier comment. Good point about the extra vertical space added by `\\ ` in the translation line. I use `expex`, not `linguex`, and in that package the final `//` in the translation line is required.